# Convert delimited string to array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

The [Logitech Media Server CLI](https://github.com/elParaguayo/LMS-CLI-Documentation/blob/master/LMS-CLI.md#0.1_GC) returns a list of media players on the network as a string. Once I've stripped off a few initial parameters, I'm left with this:

```
playerindex:0 playerid:00:04:20:17:df:db
uuid:e03808651b33791ebd7654ecb558a659 ip:192.168.2.213:20806
name:Living Room Duet seq_no:0 model:receiver modelname:Squeezebox
Receiver power:1 isplaying:1 displaytype:none isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:77 playerindex:1 playerid:00:04:20:17:1c:ea
uuid:6366878c87380f33779c3832be86b4eb ip:192.168.2.214:19359
name:Bedroom seq_no:0 model:receiver modelname:Squeezebox Receiver
power:1 isplaying:0 displaytype:none isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:77 playerindex:2 playerid:00:04:20:1e:d3:59
uuid:1c8b751b20f7e4c6977e98de03060a53 ip:192.168.2.215:23163
name:Living Room seq_no:0 model:boom modelname:Squeezebox Boom power:1
isplaying:0 displaytype:graphic-160x32 isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:57
```

*NOTE: the above is pasted with newline characters NOT in the original string, for ease of reading (and was also edited by another user to make it more readable). The string has NO newline characters within it.*

As you can see, the string is delimited by spaces, however you may notice there are player names containing a space. As such I cannot simply use `newArray = array.split(" ")` then loop through x number of parameters to build an array of objects, which is my aim, because these spaces throw off the chunk length of the array.

The second problem I can spot is that the IP address and MAC addresses contain colons, which causes an additional problem.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't be done as you have ip address and some other keys which uses `:` in values, so i don't think you can unless you know all the key names beforehand

Comment: I think you can if you split on space, a-z*, colon... maybe

Comment: pls add RegEx tag to the question, thanks

Comment: Surely there's a way to get the CLI to output something more machine readable. For example, in the docs it looks like these items are separated by newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done manually because the properties have doesn't have random position, so we can split each known property.

```js
var str = '...your string here...';

// Remove new line and split `playerindex`
var split = str.split("\n").join(' ').split('playerindex:');
var take = ['playerindex', 'playerid', 'uuid', 'ip', 'name', 'seq_no', 'model', 'modelname', 'power', 'isplaying', 'displaytype', 'isplayer', 'canpoweroff', 'connected', 'firmware'];

// Remove empty string
split.shift();

var collection = [];
for(var i=0; i<split.length; i++){

  // Prepare the object and current string to be parsed
  var currentData = {};
  var currentStr = split[i];

  // Split each known property
  for(var j=1; j<take.length; j++){
    currentStr = currentStr.split(' '+take[j]+':', 2);

    // Does the property not exist?
    if(currentStr.length === 1){
      currentStr = currentStr[0];
      continue;
    }

    // The first index is value from the previous property
    currentData[take[j-1]] = currentStr[0];

    // The last index still need to be parsed
    currentStr = currentStr[1];
  }

  // Put the last string as the last property value
  currentData[take[j-1]] = currentStr.trim();

  // Finished, let's push to the collection
  collection.push(currentData);
}

console.log(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, something that certainly works for the example you've provided is, to put a `\n` in place of the last space before a sequence of non-whitespace characters `\S` immediately followed by a `:`; and then splitting the string at every `\n`

For example:

```js
var str = "playerindex:0 playe... and the rest of the string...";
var arrayOfSplits = str.replace(/(\s)(\S*\:)/g,"\n$2").split("\n");
```

A potential issue I see with this is that it's assuming that there aren't going to be any `\n`s in the string. Of course, this can be solved by using another character/pattern which is known to not appear in the string.

Comment: Hopefully I have not misunderstood your answer, please note the string posted above was reformatted (by a suggestion from a SO user) and appears to have newlines within the string. I believe I posted it without, i.e. as a single line and it may have undergone some editing since posting! Either way the string I am trying to work with has no newline characters. Very sorry if this was not clear, but I have updated original question to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and my solution was based on the assumption that there are no newline characters in the string you're trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression multiple matches `|` to extract your data as formatted:

```js
const re = /(playerindex):(\d+)|(playerid):(([0-9a-f]{2}:?){6})|(uuid):([0-9a-f]{32})|(ip):(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d+)|(\sname):((\w+)\s)+|(seq_no):(\d+)|(model):(\w+)|(modelname):((\w+)\s)+|(power):(\d+)|(isplaying):(\d)|(displaytype):([a-z\-0-9]+)|(isplayer):(\d)|(canpoweroff):(\d)|(connected):(\d)|(firmware):(\d+)/gi;

const formatted = `playerindex:0 playerid:00:04:20:17:df:db uuid:e03808651b33791ebd7654ecb558a659 ip:192.168.2.213:20806
name:Living Room Duet seq_no:0 model:receiver modelname:Squeezebox
Receiver power:1 isplaying:1 displaytype:none isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:77 playerindex:1 playerid:00:04:20:17:1c:ea
uuid:6366878c87380f33779c3832be86b4eb ip:192.168.2.214:19359
name:Bedroom seq_no:0 model:receiver modelname:Squeezebox Receiver
power:1 isplaying:0 displaytype:none isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:77 playerindex:2 playerid:00:04:20:1e:d3:59
uuid:1c8b751b20f7e4c6977e98de03060a53 ip:192.168.2.215:23163
name:Living Room seq_no:0 model:boom modelname:Squeezebox Boom power:1
isplaying:0 displaytype:graphic-160x32 isplayer:1 canpoweroff:1
connected:1 firmware:57`.replace("\n", ' ');

const group = formatted.match(re).reduce((acc, cur, arr) => {
  let [, name, value] = cur.match(/(\w+):(.*)/);
  name = name.trim();

  let entry;

  if (name === 'playerindex') {
    entry = {}
    acc.push(entry);
  } else {
    entry = acc[acc.length - 1];
  }

  entry[name] = value.trim();

  return acc;
}, []);


document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(group, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"><pre>
```